# Another Question on Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions on $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ such that for every $x\in X$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ is convex. Show that the limit of $f_n(x)$ as n goes to infinity exists at every point $x\in X$. Is it always true that the integrals $\int_Xf_nd\mu$ tend to $\int_Xfd\mu$ under these assumptions.

Again, I have my intuitions about the problem but am having some serious trouble in writing it up. I am almost certain that the second part is false and am attempting to devise a counter example.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to be convex?

Comment: 2$f_{n+1}(x)\le f_n+f_{n+2}(x)$ for every x

Comment: Does $f$ take on values in the extended reals in case $f_n(x)$ diverges as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Yes, $f\in [0,\infty]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sequence $f_n(x)$ is 'convex' we have that $f_{n+2}(x)-f_{n+1}(x) \ge f_{n+1}(x)-f_{n}(x) $ for all $n,x$.

For fixed $x$, the sequence $\delta_n = f_{n+1}(x)-f_{n}(x)$ is non-decreasing and hence $\delta_n \uparrow \delta$ (possibly $+\infty$).

If $\delta \le 0$, then $\delta_n \le 0$ for all $n$, and since $f_{n+1}(x) = \delta_n + ...+\delta_1 + f_1(x)$, we see that $f_n(x)$ is decreasing and so has a limit (possibly $-\infty$).

If $\delta > 0$, we see that eventually  $\delta_n \ge 0$, and hence $f_n(x)$ is eventually increasing and has a limit (possibly $+\infty$).

An unsatisfactory example on $\mathbb{R}$ is give by $f_n(x) = {1 \over n} |x|$. Then $\int f_n = + \infty$, but $\int f = 0$.